# DOCKER: Running shell script inside container hangs

Tags: docker, lamp

- I am currently trying to dockerize a codeigniter application cloned from [here](https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-composer-installer).
- I used a base lamp stack image from docker hub found [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/firespring/apache2-php)

My dockerfile looks like this currently:

```
FROM firespring/apache2-php

WORKDIR /var/www/spaceship
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["bin/server.sh"]
```

But when I try to run it it with:

```
$ docker run -p 1234:8000 spaceship
```

it hangs.

I tried verifying if my base image was not compatible with it:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash spaceship

root@fa09751cd081:/var/www/spaceship# ls

Dockerfile  README.md  application  bin  composer.json  composer.lock  favicon.ico  public  vendor

root@fa09751cd081:/var/www/spaceship# bin/server.sh

PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24 Development Server started at Sat Apr  6 02:51:44 2019
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000
Document root is /var/www/spaceship/public
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

but apparently it works inside the container locally.

So I guess my question is how do i write the proper dockerfile for this?

Comment: Open another terminal and check with `docker ps` and see if you have any container of desired type running.As @Mihai said , use the `-d` flag to have your container run in the background.

Comment: If it says `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000` it will never be reachable from outside the container.  You need to change something, usually in code, to make it say `Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8000`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try and add "-d"  to your docker run command:

```
docker run -d -p 1234:8000 spaceship
```